# Using shared hash in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, hash, shared

Why I get this error?

> Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at thr_hash.pl line 8.

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h:shared;

threads->create(sub{
    $h{manager} = {
        name => 'John',
        surname => 'Doe',
        age => 27
    };
})->detach;

sleep 1;

print Dumper \%h;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use shared_clone() when using a variable (anonymous hash in this case) in an assignment.:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h:shared;

threads->create(sub{
    $h{manager} = shared_clone({
        name => 'John',
        surname => 'Doe',
        age => 27
    });
})->detach;

sleep 1;

print Dumper \%h;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'manager' => {
                         'surname' => 'Doe',
                         'name' => 'John',
                         'age' => 27
                       } 
        };
```